# Need to show custom info message in data table header , is there any in built option?

Tags: datatables

I need to add custom info in datatable header.Please refer below pic for more reference.
[image: Need to add custom info in data datatable header]

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by inserting [Custom Element](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/dom_toolbar.html) in DOM positioning of DataTable.

> DataTables inserts DOM elements around the table to control DataTables features, and you can make use of this mechanism as well to insert your own custom elements.

For example:

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
   "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip'
} );

$("div.toolbar").html('<b>Custom tool bar! Text/images etc.</b>');
```

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/pf4vme39/) for demonstration.

Comment: @YogeshwarTanwar, consider accepting the answer if it helped you out.