# Howto dispose custom button (add) in the toolbar datatables

Tags: button, datatables, customization, dispose

I am trying to add a button align to left side in the toolbar of my datatable. 
In the rigth side I have 5 button for export.
I am newbie with Datatables and I am not an expertise with javascript, so If someone can help me I apreciate.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#TableId').DataTable(
{
    columnDefs: [
        { "width": "5%", "targets": [0] },
        { "className": "text-left custom-middle-align", "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] }
    ],
    dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
    buttons: [

        {extend: 'copy'},
        {extend: 'csv'},
        {extend: 'excel', title: 'ExampleFile'},
        {extend: 'pdf', title: 'ExampleFile'},

        {extend: 'print',
            customize: function (win){
                $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');
                $(win.document.body).find('table')
                        .addClass('compact')
                        .css('font-size', 'inherit');
            }
        }
    ],
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax:
        {
            url: "/Plugin/GetData",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON"

        },
    rowId: "Sr",
    columns: [
                {
                "className": 'details-control sorting_disabled',
                "orderable": false,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": ''
                },
                { "data": "Sr" },
                { "data": "OrderTrackNumber" },
                { "data": "Quantity" },
                { "data": "ProductName" },
                { "data": "SpecialOffer" },
                { "data": "UnitPrice" },
                { "data": "UnitPriceDiscount" }
    ],
    order: [[1, "asc"]]
});
```

I have this
[image]

And I want this
[image]

Thank in advance.

Best regards.

Jolynice

Comment: You want to embed your `add` button just above the `length` control of the datatable or left side of `length` control?

Comment: Hello mmushtaq, left side of length control.

Comment: Then you can inject `add` button in dom positioning of datatable. Please refer to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43951472/3814721)